# Zipper to iterate over list in Scala

Tags: scala, zipper

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980275/zipper-vs-iterator-for-walking-over-a-list-or-tree). I can use an iterator, `fold`, `zip`, `foreach` and others to iterate over a list in Scala. Now I wonder if there are use cases where `Zipper` is most appropriate. Suppose I need read-only access without concurrency.

Could you give such an example and explain why the `Zipper` is the best choice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the many neat things about zippers is that they have a comonad instance, which allows us to solve a certain class of problems very elegantly.

Here's a quick example off the top of my head. Suppose that we've got a sequence of numbers and we want to do a simple form of smoothing with an exponential moving average, where the new value for each position in the list is an average of the current value and all the other values, but with more distant neighbors contributing less.

This isn't a terribly hard thing to compute imperatively, but if we use a zipper and a comonadic cobind it's not too far from a one-liner:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val weights = Stream.from(1).map(1.0 / math.pow(2, _))

def sumNeighborWeights(neighbors: Stream[Double]) =
  neighbors.fzipWith(weights)(_ * _).sum

def smooth(data: NonEmptyList[Double]) = data.toZipper.cobind { z =>
  (z.focus + sumNeighborWeights(z.lefts) + sumNeighborWeights(z.rights)) / 3
}
```

Now if we write:

```
val result = smooth(NonEmptyList[Double](0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)).toList
```

We'll get the moral equivalent of:

```
List(1 / 24, 1 / 12, 1 / 6, 1 / 3, 1 / 6, 1 / 12, 1 / 24)
```

Which is what we want, given how we defined the problem.

Comment: Is it quadratic ? Can it be linear _without_ zipper ?

Comment: It is, but I'm not sure there's a linear solution in this case.

Comment: Well ... that is, good zipper examples are inherently quadratic.

Comment: Not necessarily—you may only be interested in a fixed-size neighborhood around the focus, for example. Also note that there are lots of nice things about zippers—the imperative-like ease of "modification", for example.